# Typescript ENUM's

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, graphql

I have list of options that needs to be stored as an ENUM. The issues is that the options are all alpha numeric.

Example List

```
 1.134/2394 x 3-xyz
 2.123/234 y 3-ery 
 3.345/99 t 4-red
 4.4.1hv 3 secondary
 5.2.51hv 3 secondary
 6.1.61hv 3 secondary
```

How do we store this as options in Typescript. Any thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the version of typescript you are using?
Also are you OK to have `enum Season {    Winter = "winter",` }` something this kind of assignment?

Comment: Nope, I don't prefer assiging values like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like this right?

```
enum x {
    '1.134/2394 x 3-xyz' = 2,
    '2.123/234 y 3-ery',
}

console.log(x['2.123/234 y 3-ery'])
// this will print '3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `enums` are javascript objects. When you creates an `enum` you've a choice to access the object.

So if your keys contains the alphanumeric and spaces, then you can't access with `.` after enum name like - `StatusCode.Ok 2`  This will produce error.

So coming to your case, you need to access your object either with the number you've assigned or the key you've assigned. Its your choice. So you can access like this `StatusCode['OK']`.

Take a look at below example. 
[Source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=25&ssc=2&pln=18&pc=1#code/PTAEFEDsFcFsGdQEMBOBTZoBmakBdp1kATYtY0PAe1ACkkA3JAZQGMUBLABz1A8lAAVAJ5c0bTjwCwAKBCgA7gAsOrJaFhIA1mkQdeueBzQpKNJUkjEANhkhJY5UPDR5EVLKFZVI8PJbcAOllZeQAhYVAyLCRoa15LUDQYWD5EFIAjE1AMpBdiABpnfxQ8fgBzZF4ALxMqAtCwSwpcNVAqHg4fNOR4I3LIJ0T%20djRHSF4MyJ80QKEVPXhG0GgXLDjFJWTKLdAma2gMDnSqXg5YLipSgOCZWWS4UABhKgu8%20AARDnRWMu6Ab1koFAADkrnglA0ZMDwHk8FDgcwqNAIQjQAB1XR4WQAXxCcjAEWQkEgp3wFWJSRS7U6PiKwmRzlcOww%200OAG5liN0OM3F4fGUYBgsChXjt8HskAc0AAufEPVLMfwEeAvMiIQHQ0AAeQA0qAALygABMAAZTWiwkhiAAlNAAR0OfkNoAALOa0QBVewopRXDi1QpA0AABSQwl5dsd33IaIAYlcMhxSMk0WC8AnoFZcfj5ABNRnoHDoSCsDCJBU5SKrClQOAghyzABqUsO%20O8vl4flQgvKXx%20fwERpebz6-bQvy6kECsL8nJkHedrEIJbwSvwqxd65Vat0gT18%20WdYQzmgXEupWQrDLfQpxHwSD4Agyp3UxBjk58iBFYp0wmW1CStKRTNEBhxmKAf63LIi68FQWggnAWSmEa26rLu8D7rq86we0CFISYACSVhoAAHluyroVQ6oANoAER6nRAC6OFfl2eCcJA5RWraDpOrwqGUaq1G6DR7qmixuZgMeiCsIkWRRBwWDFskvB4KIuggcUnGVOpYg9N4sCwD4tzyJ6RhcZgfg6V4iSaDofAGHkximIBZAZNA5RFFkcmrBgEJoMsbLlrwKBZmUjhRFQuigKSoV8TGoAMtAEHWFQ8ErFwLKxQRKDQTIlYAOKNmGxDEVwKKgJqwKellRp0Z6IZ0WiHxUAoQ6gHRHzauiILNcGAAyaBYAJnUDeAcaCP1Wo2hw5RKKNdE2oRhUABJTTmdwEqAhGeMligBBB6DENAZbZZk2QeO0GQAFYTny-BJciKDLPQTASNwoXhecaD0oyckCKM%20DlvynZUnA%20XyAAgqDzoKgA5IgwU9OgXDWEgZYUFMQgaR9PBRIQFQASgljwFwHDo4O7R7c9-JkEU-B%20LgFBXVkFJpfBThnkFHCPokVC3fdVSgGFEw-fluGVgAssiLhQ5%20AjVaAMt%20a17VoirLi1dqKJGPTwaa2gtXEXrgUyHiW24RYVi2Ib8tU0aAAUGODjKyuy2g9tTgAlIaAB8VXBvACj6G0zsK77SvAnJLju35XsmYbauQHKWrAtHX5ULYgRpeUjt0YboDJ3R3vzun6cZOg2hl6AFs4oe227U9KUc1owsBZQJO%20OTtgUG9LDsJ9f0pQDTJm-IfoKNlr7ZAqiBkccCTuILvyIKB6yloO8BQhPbVoAw2R2wrPRxSy6CQ2AggLD0UrwDQHHgVgVzZWoE5t0g5RIIzvBH4OgRJ21SAXJfDJn8rsYOod1DdjwGMVST5TagGtjYNAv8pwXwgCkWSiRiA0GMkQCEiQITHGHrZAQVcKB4KOAIAKywRBiDxrwJBL54KpxAMsBaeAuDwBlCABQfDAh6V0IPHg6MuKBCuOUYAODWDwGAEw9KWhgBz0CAtWA1ggA)

```js
/*
enum StatusCodes {
  OK = 200,
    BadRequest = 400,
    Unauthorized,
    PaymentRequired,
    Forbidden,
    NotFound
};
*/

// The above enum is converted to the Javasscript object like this. 

var StatusCodes;
(function(StatusCodes) {
  StatusCodes[StatusCodes["OK"] = 200] = "OK";
  StatusCodes[StatusCodes["BadRequest"] = 400] = "BadRequest";
  StatusCodes[StatusCodes["Unauthorized"] = 401] = "Unauthorized";
  StatusCodes[StatusCodes["PaymentRequired"] = 402] = "PaymentRequired";
  StatusCodes[StatusCodes["Forbidden"] = 403] = "Forbidden";
  StatusCodes[StatusCodes["NotFound"] = 404] = "NotFound";
})(StatusCodes || (StatusCodes = {}));

// Ways to access the enum. 
console.log(StatusCodes.OK);
console.log(StatusCodes["OK"]);
console.log(StatusCodes["200"]);
```